# Tips on identifying CVA patients

Tags: neurology, emergency

In my work, not once i encounter old people with deterioration and i am having hard time deciding if does symptoms may be related to CVA or not and if a neurologist should be called.

I will explain by a story from the ER:
take a 70 year old women who was ok in her functioning, namely need help and diapers but communicate properly and from today there is a deterioration and she is much less communicating.

In her background - recurrent UTIs (and of course UTI may explain the deterioration) but the daughter says her UTIs are not presenting that way. 
also, she stopped her Xarelto because of Hematuria. Of course this is an alert that CVA is more likely.

But still - i ask for tips in identifying CVAs, not just in the usual weakness in one side of the body.

Thank you

Comment: What is your work? In other words, what level of medical training do you have? I think that would affect the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from typical paralysis and numbness, symptoms of a *transient ischemic attack (TIA)* or *full blown stroke* may include:

- Slurred speech or hard time understanding speech
- Dizziness or loss of balance or coordination
- Sudden severe headache: According to [Current Pain and Headache Reports, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25095904): "**Hemorrhagic strokes**, more frequently than ischemic strokes, present with distinct headaches, usually accompanied by focal neurological symptoms" (also see [Mayfield Clinic](https://mayfieldclinic.com/pe-sah.htm)); According to [MedLink](http://www.medlink.com/article/headache_associated_with_ischemic_cerebrovascular_disease): "Headache often accompanies acute **ischemic stroke.** Observational studies indicate that 15% to 40% of patients with acute ischemic stroke report headache in close temporal relation to the event."
- Impaired vision

Sources: [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/transient-ischemic-attack/symptoms-causes/syc-20355679), [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/stroke/symptoms-tia#1), [American Stroke Association](https://www.stroke.org/en/about-stroke/stroke-symptoms)

Comment: Sudden severe headache and CVA? i would think about subarachnoid hemmorhage. why CVA?

Comment: Well, why not - it's not that I invented this.

Comment: see, slurred speech from CVA can be explained easily by damaging the broca or wernike areas. 
what is the pathophysiology for headache that you may say it feets CVA? and why not to think about subarachnoid hemmorhage for sudden severe headache?

Comment: Hemorrhagic stroke could cause subarachnoid hemmorhage and this headache. I added a link in my answer. I'm not sure about exact mechanism of headache.

Comment: @Alon Sudden, severe headache is definitely a symptom of hemorrhagic stroke.

Comment: That is true, but you mean subarachnoid hemmorhage could cause hemmorhagic stroke.

Comment: No, hemorrhagic stroke causes subarachnoid hemmorhage.

Comment: yea when i think about it you are right, i realy need to think again about the terms. thank you

Comment: @Alon It's not necessary for the arachnoid mater to be involved. Headache can occur no matter where the bleed occurs.

Comment: The  Mayfield Clinic article I linked, actually mentions secondary stroke as a result of hemorrhage, but it can be also the other way around.

Comment: because of the pressure i assume. but none the less, its so classic for subarachnoid hemmorhage to cause a sudden severe headache, see berry aneurysm rapture for example, so its the first thing that came to mind.

but lets get to the important point, anymore tips on identify CVA? and i am more concerned about the ischemic strokes because i found them more confusing, lets say - how would you realize that the old lady with dizziness actually have a stroke now?

Comment: I added another source according to which ischemic stroke is also often associated with headache. So, the rest is about differential diagnosis, but I'll wait for some actual clinician to go through that.

Comment: I'm down voting this answer because it's textbook, and doesn't really relate to the OP's concerns. They stipulated "i ask for tips in identifying CVAs, not just in the usual weakness in one side of the body." Clearly they are asking for subtle signs of stroke, not signs that would alarm everybody.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, the OP asks if there are any other symptoms, such as confusion, that can raise suspicion for a stroke. I provided the evidence that they are.

Comment: Just explaining my DV, not trying to make you explain your answer.